# question about a limit of a function with 2 variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Does the following limit exist? 
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,2)}\sqrt{y^2-4}\cdot\ln(5-x^2-y^2)
$$
If it that, what is the limit? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note first that your function is defined in the domain $y^2\geq 4$ and $5-x²-y²>0$. Now let $t>0$ such that $t+\exp(-1/t)<1$. (this last inequality is true for $t$ small, as $\exp(-1/t)\to 0$ if $t>0$ and $t\to 0$). Let $x,y$  such that $y=\sqrt{4+t}$ and $x=\sqrt{1-t-\exp(-1/t)}$. We verify that $(x,y)$ is  in the domain of  existence of $f$ (for $t>0$ small), $(x,y)\to (1,2)$ as $t\to 0$ and that $f(x,y)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$. Hence the limit does not exists.

Comment: @boaz You are welcome.